# Change the current page of an AJAX datatables

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I'm currently having a datatable with some data. The issue is as follows:
Lest have a total of 91 rows and we set paging to 10 rows per page. This gives us 10 pages with the last page with only 1 row.

I'm using the .ajax.reload() method from the DataTables API to refresh the table whenever I make any change on it and I pass the "keepPage" parameter as true which means that if I'm on 5th page and I edit something, after the server side processing, my data will still load page 5.

However, the problem comes when I'm on the last page with only 1 row and I delete that row. My table refreshes on the 10th page and since there isn't anything more on it, it displays an empty table.

How can I change the page in this case to the previous one?

Comment: how to tell, without seeing any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`page.info()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()) to get paging information about the table before reloading with `ajax.reload()`.

Then perform the following calculations.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Get paging information
var info = table.page.info(); 

// Number of deleted rows
var numDeleted = 1;    

// Calculate number of pages after deleting rows
var numPagesAfter = Math.ceil((info.recordsDisplay - numDeleted)/info.length);

// If number of pages after deleting rows is less than total number of pages
// and the last page is displayed
if(numPagesAfter < info.pages && info.page === (info.pages - 1)){
   // Go to previous page using zero-based index
   table.page(numPagesAfter - 1);
}

// Reload table
table.ajax.reload();
```